# Error al intentar cargar vista con 2 modelos unidos esta vista esta conformada por 2 vistas parciales donde cada una usa un modelo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, spring-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Trabajamos con MVC 5 / C# / VS2019 / Boostrap / SQL Server.

Les comento he tratado de hacer funcional esta parte del código del proyecto que realizamos, y recibo este mensaje de error, he buscado ejemplos en la red al respecto pero de lo investigado y aplicado no he tenido éxito al respecto, por ello estoy en el foro solicitando de su experiencia para lograr resolver el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He revisado ejemplos pero no he logrado hacer funcionar lo planteado a continuación:

Cuento con una vista, que tiene un botón que al pulsarlo llama a una modal, es en esta modal que se llama a la vista que tiene a su ves dos vistas parciales cada una con 1 modelo. Hice lo siguiente genere un modelo que uniera los 2 modelos a llamar:

```
namespace Calificaciones.Models.ViewModels{
public class Califica_AgilizaCaptura_Parcial_VM
{
    public List<CalificaParcialListaAlumnos_ViewModel> Calificaciones { get; set; }
    public AgilizaCaptura_Parcial_VM AgilizaCalificar { get; set; }
}}
```

En la vista que llama a las 2 parciales :

```html
@model Calificaciones.Models.ViewModels.Califica_AgilizaCaptura_Parcial_VM
@Html.Partial("_AgilizaCaptura", Model.AgilizaCalificar)
@Html.Partial("_CalficarGrupo", Model.Calificaciones)
```

En la vista parcial **_AgilizaCaptura**, lo que hago es llamar al modelo de la vista que ocupare y es aquí donde tal vez este incorrecto hacer para hacer uso del modelo en la vista es que lo llamo de la siguiente forma:

```html
@model Calificaciones.Models.ViewModels.AgilizaCaptura_Parcial_VM
.......aqui el código de la vista....
```

Para la vista parcial **_CalificarGrupo** hago algo similar:

```html
@model List<Calificaciones.Models.ViewModels.CalificaParcialListaAlumnos_ViewModel>
......aqui el código de la vista parcial.......
```

Aclaro que la vista parcial **_CalificarGrupo** es para mostrar un listado de alumnos para calificar y que es funcional, pero ahora que hay necesidad de incrustar 2 vistas parciales una para la captura de calificaciones y otra para subir un archivo de excel con las calificaciones y tomarlas de ese archivo y aplicar una calificación global al listado de alumnos.

Espero no hacer rebuscado lo comentado, de antemano agradezco las atenciones a mi mensaje.

Comment: Así como lo planteas parece todo correcto, no tendrás 2 vistas con el mismo nombre??

Answer (score 0):

Para llamar a la vista que contiene las 2 vistas parciales con diferente modelo, se tiene esta línea en el código:

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCapturaParcial", "Captura", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return  AddFormCapturaParcial(this)", @class = "form-vertical", }))

Y este controlador recibe la petición así:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddCapturaParcial(List<CalificaParcialListaAlumnos_ViewModel> CalificaParcial)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
```

El error al parecer esta en esta parte.